# How to sum up rows (that are not blank) from input values in a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input-field, rowcount

I've added input fields into a table. What I'm looking to do is to count all of the rows and add them into a table row total. Ideally I want these to have a value of 0.5 for each row that has an input value. I'm trying to do this with javascript but I don't know where to start.

On the total column, I'm trying to get the total count value within the rows.
So for example row 1 to count the number of non-blank input values I want this total to appear where the current value is Total1. and the same iteration for the other rows for Total2, Total3 etc.

```css
table{
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 1620px;
}

td.staff-input{
    max-width: 30px;
    background-color: white;

}

input:invalid{
    background-color: white;
    border-color: #efefef;
}

input:valid{

    font-weight:bold;
    border-color: orange;
}

input.staff-input{
    max-width: 30px;

}

table {
    empty-cells: hide;
    background: white;
}

td.dow{
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #34a853;
}

th{
    background-color: #34a853;
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    width: 30px;
}

th.total,th.additional-notes {
    width: 50px;
}

tr.staff-name:nth-child(odd) input:invalid{
    background-color: #efefef;
}
tr.staff-name:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #efefef;
}

td.dow{
    background-color: white;
}

td{
    overflow: hidden;
}
input{
    width: 30px;
}

th.date{
    width: 4000px;
}

.staff-input input{
    width:30px;
}

.activities input{
    width: 200px;
    border-color:#efefef;
}

tr.staff-name td.dow{
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="table-styling.css">
<head>
<p>This is my awesome rota</p>
</head>
<Body>

    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="date">Day</th>
            <th>Staff Name</th>
            <th>08:30</th>
            <th>09:00</th>
            <th>09:30</th>
            <th>10:00</th>
            <th>10:30</th>
            <th>11:00</th>
            <th>11:30</th>
            <th>12:00</th>
            <th>12:30</th>
            <th>13:00</th>
            <th>13:30</th>
            <th>14:00</th>
            <th>14:30</th>
            <th>15:00</th>
            <th>15:30</th>
            <th>16:00</th>
            <th>16:30</th>
            <th>17:00</th>
            <th>17:30</th>
            <th>18:00</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Activities</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<tr class="staff-name">
<td rowspan="0" class="dow">Mon 20 Mar 2023</td>
<td>Marion</td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td>Total1</td>
<td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="staff-name">
<td>Nicola</td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td>Total2</td>
<td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="staff-name">
 <td>Fiona</td> 
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
 <td>Total3</td>
 <td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="staff-name">
<td>Teresa</td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td>Total4</td>
<td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="staff-name">
<td>Lilly</td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td>Total5</td>
<td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="staff-name">
<td>Jemma</td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td>Total6</td>
<td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="staff-name">
<td>Rachel</td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
<td>Total7</td>
<td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="staff-name">
    <tr class="staff-name">
        <td>Gemma</td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td>Total8</td>
        <td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
</Body>
```

I've tried to find some examples of code for this but all I've found is JavaScript for summing numerical values not non-empty values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt to achieve it using javascript. Not sure if i understand your problem correctly. For each input it will increment the counter

```js
const allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.staff-input input');
allInputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', handleValueChange);
});

function handleValueChange(e) {
  const parentTr = e.target.closest(".staff-name");
  const totalElem = parentTr.querySelector('.total');
  let total = 0;
  parentTr.querySelectorAll('.staff-input input').forEach(function(input) {
    if (input.value !== "") {
      total++;
    }
  });
  totalElem.innerHTML = total;
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 1620px;
}

td.staff-input {
  max-width: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}

input:invalid {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: #efefef;
}

input:valid {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-color: orange;
}

input.staff-input {
  max-width: 30px;
}

table {
  empty-cells: hide;
  background: white;
}

td.dow {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #34a853;
}

th {
  background-color: #34a853;
  color: white;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  width: 30px;
}

th.total,
th.additional-notes {
  width: 50px;
}

tr.staff-name:nth-child(odd) input:invalid {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

tr.staff-name:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

td.dow {
  background-color: white;
}

td {
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  width: 30px;
}

th.date {
  width: 4000px;
}

.staff-input input {
  width: 30px;
}

.activities input {
  width: 200px;
  border-color: #efefef;
}

tr.staff-name td.dow {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <p>This is my awesome rota</p>
</head>

<Body>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="date">Day</th>
        <th>Staff Name</th>
        <th>08:30</th>
        <th>09:00</th>
        <th>09:30</th>
        <th>10:00</th>
        <th>10:30</th>
        <th>11:00</th>
        <th>11:30</th>
        <th>12:00</th>
        <th>12:30</th>
        <th>13:00</th>
        <th>13:30</th>
        <th>14:00</th>
        <th>14:30</th>
        <th>15:00</th>
        <th>15:30</th>
        <th>16:00</th>
        <th>16:30</th>
        <th>17:00</th>
        <th>17:30</th>
        <th>18:00</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Activities</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="staff-name">
        <td rowspan="0" class="dow">Mon 20 Mar 2023</td>
        <td>Marion</td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="total">Total1</td>
        <td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="staff-name">
        <td>Nicola</td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="total">Total2</td>
        <td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="staff-name">
        <td>Fiona</td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="total">Total3</td>
        <td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="staff-name">
        <td>Teresa</td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="total">Total4</td>
        <td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="staff-name">
        <td>Lilly</td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="total">Total5</td>
        <td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="staff-name">
        <td>Jemma</td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="total">Total6</td>
        <td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="staff-name">
        <td>Rachel</td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="total">Total7</td>
        <td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="staff-name">
        <td>Gemma</td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="staff-input"><input maxlength="3" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" required></td>
        <td class="total">Total8</td>
        <td class="activities"><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</Body>
```

Comment: If you want to increase total by 0.5 for each entered value. then change "total++" to "total += 0.5"

Comment: thanks so much for this! do you know how I would show where to put the value in the html elements for this and where I would the JS file in the html document? I'm trying to show the total value count in the area which is highlighted and replace the text like this: https://ibb.co/tcbwxyc but for each row.

Comment: Got it to work! thank you so much that has helped incredibly!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood what you want but this code (if I'm not mistaken) should help you.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){


    // I place a button on the HTML Code and when is clicked
    $('#myButton').click(function(){

        // For Each Line with Class Name "staff-name"
        $('.staff-name').each(function(index){

            // Initialization Total For the Current Line
            let lineTotal = 0;

            // For Each Input Type Text with Class Name "staff-input" of the Current Line
            $(this).find('.staff-input input[type=text]').each(function(indexCol) { 

                // Get the value enterred
                let value = $(this).val();

                // Increment 
                lineTotal = lineTotal+(value/2);

            });

            // Display in Console
            console.log(index+" - "+lineTotal);

            // Place the Total in input type Text of Cell 'activities' of the Current line
            $(this).find('.activities input[type=text]').val(lineTotal);
        });
        // Fin - For Each Line with Class Name "staff-name"

    });
});
</script>
```

The code above is JQuery.
And you can put this code just before the body end tag < / body >

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm really new to JavaScript. Where / how would I reference the JavaScript script in the HTML doc? Also How would I replace the static value for the counted total value in the html doc: https://ibb.co/tcbwxyc

Comment: I modified the code in order to put the result of the row in the "total" field (and to explain even better in the comments the principles used). And this code is to be placed just before the end of your body :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this it is really appreciated. But I'm looking for a JavaScript solution. Also is there a reason why it's referencing the total in the activities column instead of the Total column?

Comment: If my answer and the code present in the answer helped you, you can vote for this one. It improves my user level here and allows me more access and flatters my ego too :)
As for JavaScript. Do you want to do this in Javascript at all costs? Why don't you want JQuery..? JQuery is actually a JavaScript library.
And as for the placement of the result of the line, I placed it in the input field present at the end of the line using the `val()` function. But it can be placed in an end of line cell using the `html()` function